# How to make argparse split nargs='+' from nargs=REMAINDER

Tags: python, argparse

I am using argparse to parse several positional arguments as `input` and then several positional arguments as `output`. Since the number of arguments in not bounded, I am trying to use `--` as a separator. I have typically been successful with the `--` separator using `nargs=argparse.REMAINDER`, so I tried this:

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("input", nargs='+')
parser.add_argument("output", nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)

args = parser.parse_args("input1 input2 -- output1 outpu2".split())
print(args)
```

However, all arguments are put into `input` and I get this output:

```
Namespace(input=['input1', 'input2', 'output1', 'outpu2'], output=[])
```

The `--` is correctly consumed but it does not act as separator.

Is there a way to achieve this using `argparse`?

Comment: While `REMAINDER` and '--' have the same effect of treating flagged strings (`--foobar') as plain strings, they don't work together.  The '+' is greedy, getting everything to the end.  It's hard to use two open-ended positionals at once (or even a open ended optional).

Comment: Can you just split the list later, based on the position of `--` in the raw `argv`?

Comment: Also, you can probably make a custom plugin for this. I'll look into it later if I have time.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I did try the manual split approach but then I lost the nice help text for the options

Answer (score 4):

You can define a custom action which takes care of dividing the set of arguments, using (almost) any delimiter you like, into input and output files.

```
import argparse


class PartitionedValues(argparse.Action):
    def __init__(self, *args, delim="+++", **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.delim = delimiter

    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string):
        files = namespace.input = []
        namespace.output = []
        for f in values:
            if f == self.delim:
                files = namespace.output
            else:
                files.append(f)


p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument("files", action=PartitionedValues, nargs='+')
args = p.parse_args()
print(args.input)
print(args.output)
```

Then a call like

```
script.py file1 file2 +++ file3 file4
```

would produce

```
['file1', 'file2']
['file3', 'file4']
```

as output. (Note that `--` itself, and apparently anything starting with `--`, would trigger the end of processing for the `files` parameter, so I used `+++`
as the default delimiter instead.)

I also made the delimiter configurable on a per-option basis. You could change the definition of the `files` argument to

```
p.add_argument("files", action=PartitionedValues, delim="+=+", nargs="+")
```

then call your script with

```
script.py file1 file2 +=+ file3 file4
```

to get the same output.

Comment: Thank you, very ingenious use of the action parameter. However, this ends up forcing the user of the tool to construct rather artificial command lines.

Comment: @Jacobo. How? This literally does exactly what the question wants (replace `+=+` with `--`)

Comment: `--` has a specific, [hard-coded meaning](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/argparse.py#L1832) inside `argparse` that makes it unavailable for use as anything other than a signal to stop processing arguments as options.

Comment: @chepner: Not just inside `argparse`. It's pretty much a standard meaning which all utilities should respect.

Comment: Right, but as it's a convention, I wanted to emphasize that there was an actual internal behavior based on that convention that you can't override without significantly modifying the internals of `argparse`.

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't. `--` is used to separate named ("optional") arguments from positional arguments, not to split positional arguments into subsegments. That's why the docs say (emphasis added; quote is from `nargs='*'` but there's no difference except that `'+'` requires at least one argument):

> `'*'` All command-line arguments present are gathered into a list. **Note that it generally doesn’t make much sense to have more than one positional argument with `nargs='*'`**, but multiple optional arguments with `nargs='*'` is possible.

Why don't you define a flag `--output` (with `nargs='+'` or even `nargs='*'`) and invoke your program with the more explicit

```
input1 input2 --output output1 output2
```

(Use a short flagname if you're concerned about typing eight characters.)

Comment: Thank you, I suspected this although I missed that sentence in the docs. I considered the use of an explicit flag but I typically reserve those for optional parameters and wanted to ensure I was nor overseeing anything.